# Will the Android OS kill my IntentService under normal circumstances?

Tags: android, intentservice

Will the Android OS kill my `IntentService` under normal circumstances or do I need to worry about any variables being reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the Android OS kill my IntentService under normal circumstances

Yes. IntentServices will be paused,stopped and destroyed when there are no waiting intents at the whim of the OS.

> do I need to worry about any variables being reset?

There are no guarantees about variable values being retained. You should use onCreate to configure the initial state of the service and, in my experience, it works best if you don't maintain state outside of the lifecycle of the service.

Comment: Are normal services different? The service will be created once and constantly refresh the broadcast with calculated data obtained from current user location.

Comment: A bound service can be configured to be retained when not doing work. Typically, I stay away from that if possible. The stopping and starting of the service does not seem to introduce much load to the app if that is what is concerning you.

Comment: No, that doesn't concern me. What concerns me is that the service will contain variables that, if reset, would cause incorrect values for the app. (it contains location history, time history, etc.)

Comment: The place to store this information isn't in variables then. The nature of a service is something with an indeterminate, self contained life cycle. If you want the information persisted for the duration of the app, you'll need to manage that using the lifecycle of the service.

Comment: @DoctorOreo: "The service will be created once and constantly refresh the broadcast with calculated data obtained from current user location" -- that should not be an `IntentService` in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I got to thinking about that - it should be a regular `Service`, correct?

Comment: If you have state information that will persist from request to request, you will have to use a standard service.